# Placing random game objects on canvas in random position with specific distance

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new on unity and am trying to create a top-down game.

My Main camera projection set to Orthographic.

I added a canvas with Render Mode of "Screen Space - Camera" and UI Scale Mode of "Scale With Screen Size"  to hold my joystick and other UI element to support different resolutions. Also I added another canvas with the same settings to hold the walls and doors (Because they should be at the border or edge of screen along with different resolution!). I need to place some objects to the screen, I can do it by random with specific distance or by creating empty game objects on screen (inside canvas) and bind them to the script then place my Prefabs to their (empty `GameObject`) location.

The issue is I can't understand the object position in Canvas and Screen, I instantiate my prefabs to the empty gameobject position on Canvas, but it's been placed some where else.

Here's the 3d view of my scene:

[image: my scene]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Camera.main.screenToWorldPoint` and use a random float or integer for the x and z coordinates. If you set the random number to be between the lower right corner in world space and the upper left corner in world space, you will get a random position inside the walls.

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work!! Here's my code: Camera.main.screenToWorldPoint(EmptyGameObjectOnCanvas.transform.position), but my prefabs is placed out of screen now.

Comment: Instead of using a separate canvas to adjust your walls, try moving the walls by using screenToWorldPoint and then use the position of the walls to create a random position.

Comment: Thanks to your patience, Actually I currently generate random positions by the position of the Doors which is the same as what you said, the issue is if I don't hold the doors and walls in canvas, how they can be adjusted in different resolutions? I want them to be at the edges and corners of the screen always.

Comment: I am unsure as to if this would be much better, but you could try putting an empty game object in the canvas in the lower right corner, and then adjust the walls to line up with that in world space. Perhaps that would help you get positions for your random objects.